# Change textarea height on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've defined a textarea height and button is set to display none. I want to change the the textarea height (to a fixed height) and show the button if i click inside the textaea.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <textarea class="ta"></textarea>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
textarea{
    height:15px; 
    width: 200px;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

button{
    display:none;
}
```

As you can see that the textarea has height 15px. So, as soon i click in it, i want to change the height to 100px and also want to show the button.

You can see the same code in [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fZHMF/). Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind to the `click` event of the `textarea`:

```
$("textarea").click(function() {
   $(this).height(100);
   $("button").show();
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/fZHMF/10/). You may want to make those selectors more specific so as not to apply to every `textarea` and `button` element on the page.

Answer (score 5):

@user966585; look this example with `pure css`:

```
textarea{height: 15px; width: 200px;}
textarea:focus{height:100px;}
textarea:focus ~ button{display:block}
.clear{clear:both;}
button{display:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/fZHMF/15/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZHMF/14/). It will change its height on focus and return to the original size on blur. As a alternative, instead of using `.css()`, you could use `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ta').click(function () {       
         $( this ).css( "height","+=85" );
         $("button").show();

        });
```